# Angular 2 http get array of objects

Tags: angular, http, get, ionic2

I'm currently practicing with Angular2 and Ionic2. I want to retrieve data from an API (For example: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/). To retrieve the data I've made a provider with a load method:

```
load() {
if (this.currencies) {
  // already loaded data
  console.log('already has data');
  return Promise.resolve(this.currencies);
}

var url = this.baseUrl + '/coinlist';

// don't have the data yet
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json().Data)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.currencies = data;
      resolve(this.currencies);
      console.log(this.currencies);
    });
}); 
}
```

And to show the data i've made the following template structure:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let currency of currencies | orderBy : ['-Name'] | keys" (click)="itemTapped($event, currency)">
    <ion-col width-10>
    1
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-60>
    {{currency.Name}}
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-30>
    {{currency.FullName}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
```

Here I use a Pipe, as the response are Objects. However, I cant seem to make it work. Console.log shows me that the response are still objects with objects and I'm guessing that the problem lays there. (console.log is also shown twice in the console?)

Console:
[Console.log of this.currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdm8g.jpg)

For reference the Pipe class:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    if (!value) {
      return value;
    } 
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  } 
}
```

The view shows an empty list and there are no errors outputted in the console. Does anyone know how to solve this? Many thanks

Comment: your response is not an array of objects first, so check this, according to your template, it should be an array of objects.

Comment: Hi Avnesh, thank you for your response. If I remove the pipe I get the following error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.". This indicated to me that it are objects. Could you perhapse explain yourself more?

Comment: As I already told, according to your **view**, you need response: `[{"Name": "xyz", "FullName": "xyz", ...}, ...]` so that directive `*ngFor` can iterate in you view template. checkout **angular doc** if you need for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong be but it worked with AngularJS 1.x.

Rather than using objects change them to array :

```
$http.get('/*request*/').success(function(data){
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
    users.push(value);
});
/*your code*/
});
```